# Extract date from file name with import re in python

Tags: python, regex

My file name looks like as follow:

```
show_data_paris_12112019.xlsx
```

I want to extract the date only and I have tried this script:

```
date = os.path.basename(xls)
pattern = r'(?<=_)_*(?=\.xlsx)'

re.search(pattern, date).group(0)
event_date = re.search(pattern, date).group(0)
event_date_obj = datetime.strptime (event_date, '%Y%m%d')
```

but It gives me errors. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' like this

Comment: So the search fails and it returns `None`.

Comment: A great tool for testing/designing regular expressions: https://regex101.com/r/MgBArI/1 I've added (a fixed version of) your regular expression and test string. Feel free to play around with it and see what the output matches. Very useful tool.

Comment: in cases such as this, when the pattern isn't complicated, should one just use regular string methods instead of `re`? for example, the same could be achieved with `xls.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like the regex you're using is also at fault, and so it fails when trying to `group(0)` from the empty return.

Assuming all your dates are stored as digits the following regex i've made seems to work quite well.

```
(?!.+_)\d+(?=\.xlsx)
```

The next issue is when formatting the date it experiences an issue with the way you're formatting the date, to me it looks like 12112019 would be the 12/11/2019 obviously this could also be the 11/12/2019 but the basic is that we change the way strftime formats the date.

So for the date / month / year format we would use

```
# %d%m%Y
event_date_obj = datetime.strptime(event_date, '%d%m%Y')
```

And we would simply swap %d and %m for the month / date / year format. So your complete code would look something like this:

```
date = os.path.basename(xls)
pattern = "(?!.+_)\d+(?=\.xlsx)"
event_date = re.search(pattern, date).group(0)
event_date_obj = datetime.strptime (event_date, '%d%m%Y')
```

For further information on how to use strftime see https://strftime.org/.

Answer (score 1):

`_*` matches a sequence of zero or more underscore characters.

`(?<=_)` means that it has to be preceded by an underscore.

`(?=\.xlsx)` means that it has to be followed by `.xlsx`.

So this will match the `___` in `foo____.xlsx`. But it doesn't match your filename, because the data is between the underscore and `.xlsx`.

You should match `\d+` rather than `_*` between the lookbehind and lookahead.

```
pattern = r'(?<=_)\d+(?=\.xlsx)'
```

And if the data is always 8 digits, use `\d{8}` to be more specific.